# How can i integrate Tika in my Lucene project?

Tags: maven, lucene, apache-tika

I want to integrate Apache Tika in my java project. I need to get text from different file formats (excel, doc, ppt, and more..)
After some reading I understand that the only way to build tika is by downloading the src file and build it with Maven. I execute "mvn install" in the root directory of Tika src (apache-tika-0.9-src) , but i get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/6/apache-6.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.tika:tika:0.9 (C:\Users\vexler\Documents\Instal
ls\apache-tika-0.9-src\apache-tika-0.9\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.tika:tika-parent:0.9: Could
 not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:6 from/to central (http://repo1.mav
en.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect and 'pare
nt.relativePath' points at no local POM @ org.apache.tika:tika-parent:0.9, C:\Us
ers\vexler\Documents\Installs\apache-tika-0.9-src\apache-tika-0.9\tika-parent\po
m.xml, line 25, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

I really appriciate any help with this error.
Thanks :-)
Reuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Maven in your project, then life is much much simpler

Just add something like

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
   <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
   <version>0.9</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

And Maven will then download Tika and it's dependencies for you

Alternately, if you download the latest [Tika OSGi Bundle Jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-bundle/) (eg [0.9](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-bundle/0.9/tika-bundle-0.9.jar)) and unpack that, then you'll get the Tika dependencies and code in that